# Converting elements of 2D Tensor based on element mapping between old and new values?

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

I have a 2D tensor that contains the indices into some other tensor.

```
old = torch.Tensor([
    [1, 2, 12, 12],
    [0, 1, 12, 12],
    [3, 5, 12, 12],
    [7, 8, 12, 12],
    [6, 7, 12, 12],
    [9, 11, 12, 12]])
```

I have another tensor that represents a mapping between elements in the `old` tensor to a `new` tensor

```
mapping = torch.Tensor([
    [0, 0],
    [1, 6],
    [2, 1],
    [3, 6],
    [4, 2],
    [5, 6],
    [6, 3],
    [7, 6],
    [8, 4],
    [9, 6],
    [10, 5],
    [11, 6],
    [12, 6]])
```

That is, the `[:, 0]` column of `mapping` represents the values found in `old`, and the `[:, 1]` represents the values to convert the correspond to. Thus the desired output is this `new` tensor

```
new_or_desired = torch.Tensor([
    [6, 1, 6, 6],
    [0, 6, 6, 6],
    [6, 6, 6, 6],
    [6, 4, 6, 6],
    [3, 6, 6, 6],
    [6, 6, 6, 6]])
```

I have tried many iterations but my best idea yet to applying this mapping is

```
old[old == mapping[:, 0]] = mapping[:, 1]
```

But the shapes are obviously mis-matched. **How can I apply the `mapping` to convert the `old` elements to the `new` elements values?** I think I should use `scatter_` but I can't quite figure out how to apply it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with `torch.take`

```
new = torch.take(mapping[:, 1], old.long())
```